# Cannot read data correctly from a binary file

Tags: c++, byte, file-handling

I have a binary file named *input.bin* where every two characters make up one byte of data. The contents of the data are as follows:

0f00 0004 0018 0000 a040 420f 0016 03**0b**

0000 8000 0000 0000 0000 0004 0018 0000

a080 841e 0016 03**0b** 0000 8000 0000 0000

0000 0004 0018 0000 a0c0 c62d 0016 03**0b**

I am reading this file and printing its contents from the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream myFile ("input.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (myFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "File is open!\n";
        unsigned char a;
        int i = 0;
        while(myFile >> a)
        {
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << (unsigned int) a;
            i++;
            if (i%2==0)
            {
                if(i%16==0)
                    std::cout << "\n";
                else
                    std::cout << "\t";
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

The output of the code is as follows:

```
0f00    0004    0018    0000    a040    420f    0016    0300
0080    0000    0000    0000    0000    0400    1800    00a0
8084    1e00    1603    0000    8000    0000    0000    0000
0004    0018    0000    a0c0    c62d    0016    03
```

What I have observed is that the byte "0b" is not being read by the code. What might be causing this issue?

Comment: "*where every two characters make up one byte*" - so, not actually a **binary** file, but a hex-encoded **text** file? `operator>>` only works with **formatted text**, and it skips whitespace. A binary `0x0B` byte would be interpreted as a **vertical tab**, which is a whitespace character and thus skipped by `operator>>`. If the file is truly binary, you should be using `myFile.get()` or `myFile.read()` to read raw bytes from it.

Comment: Thank you @RemyLebeau, that solved the issue. I was able to read the data correctly with myFile.get()

Comment: You really are taking the long way around reading this data.  If it's actually hex-coded whitespace-separated short integers, just read them as that: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/czWKsc5qb)